# Text overlay not working with Xorg modesetting driver

Tags: c++, x11, xorg, xserver, modesetting

This is a piece of code which displays text and background rectangle When this piece of code is run with `Intel` as default `XORG driver` everything works fine both text and rectangle are being displayed,whereas when i switch to the `Modesetting` driver only the background rectangle is seen and text is not being displayed

```
#include <iostream>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>              
#include <X11/Xlib.h>            
#include <X11/Xutil.h>          
#include <X11/Xft/Xft.h> 
#include <X11/extensions/XShm.h>      
#include <sys/ipc.h> 
#include <sys/shm.h>
using namespace std;  
int main()
{
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    Screen *scn = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(display);
    int screen_num = DefaultScreen(display);
    int screen_width = DisplayWidth(display, screen_num);
    int screen_height = DisplayHeight(display, screen_num);
    int defaultScnDepth = DefaultDepthOfScreen(scn);
    Visual *visual = DefaultVisualOfScreen(scn);
    Window window=XCreateSimpleWindow(display,RootWindow(display,screen_num), 50, 50, 400, 400, 2 ,BlackPixel(display,screen_num),WhitePixel(display,screen_num));
    //XFlush(display)
    XMapWindow(display, window);
    XShmSegmentInfo shmInfo;
    XImage *xImage;
    Pixmap backPixmap;
    (xImage) = XShmCreateImage(display, visual, defaultScnDepth, ZPixmap, NULL, &shmInfo, screen_width, screen_height);
    shmInfo.shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, (xImage)->bytes_per_line * (xImage)->height, IPC_CREAT | 0777);
    shmInfo.shmaddr = (char *) shmat(shmInfo.shmid, 0, 0);
    xImage->data = shmInfo.shmaddr;
    shmInfo.readOnly = False;
    XShmAttach(display, &shmInfo);
    (backPixmap) = XShmCreatePixmap(display, window, (char *) (shmInfo.shmaddr), &shmInfo, (xImage)->width, (xImage)->height, (xImage)->depth);
    XGCValues values;
    GC gc = XCreateGC(display, backPixmap, 0, &values);
    XSync(display, false);

    Drawable drawable =backPixmap;
    visual = DefaultVisual(display, DefaultScreen(display));
    Colormap colormap = XCreateColormap(display, window, visual, AllocNone);
    //gc = XCreateGC(display, drawable, 0, &values);
    //XFlushGC(display, gc);
    const char *text = "Hello";
    XftDraw *xftDraw = NULL;
    XRenderColor xrFGColor, xrBGColor;
    XftColor     xftFGColor, xftBGColor;
    XftFont *font = NULL;
    font = XftFontOpenName( display, DefaultScreen( display ), "morpheus-18" );  
    xftDraw = XftDrawCreate(display, drawable, visual, colormap);
    int nextLineStartY, rectYRef;
    bool firstIte;
    unsigned int rectX, rectY, rectWidth, rectHeight;

    nextLineStartY = 0; rectYRef = 0;
    firstIte = true;
    rectX = 0; rectY = 0; rectWidth = 0; rectHeight = 0;

    std::istringstream strStream(text);
    std::string line;

    while(std::getline(strStream, line))

    {

        const char *lineText = line.c_str();
        if(*lineText == '\0')
        {
            nextLineStartY += rectHeight + 1;
            continue;
        }

        const char *text = lineText;
        XGlyphInfo extents;
        XftTextExtents8(display, font, (XftChar8 *)text, strlen(text), &extents);
        unsigned int width = extents.width;
        unsigned int height = extents.height;
        int ascent = extents.y;
        int lBearing = extents.x;
        rectX = 50 - lBearing - 1;
        rectY = 50 - ascent - 1;
        rectWidth = width + 2 * 1;
        rectHeight = height + 5 + 1;
        if(firstIte)
        {
            rectYRef = rectY;
            firstIte = false;
        }
        int diff = rectYRef - rectY;
        rectY += nextLineStartY + diff;
        nextLineStartY += rectHeight + 1;
        if(1)
        {
            xrBGColor.red = 0x7fff;
            xrBGColor.green= 0x7fff;
            xrBGColor.blue = 0x7fff;
            xrBGColor.alpha= 0xffff;
            XftColorAllocValue(display, visual, colormap, &xrBGColor, &xftBGColor);
            //  Draw background fill rectangle
            XftDrawRect(xftDraw, &xftBGColor, rectX, rectY, rectWidth, rectHeight);
            XftColorFree(display, visual, colormap, &xftBGColor);
        }
        xrFGColor.red =  0xbfff;
        xrFGColor.green =  0xbfff;
        xrFGColor.blue =  0xbfff;
        xrFGColor.alpha= 0xffff;
        XftColorAllocValue(display, visual, colormap, &xrFGColor, &xftFGColor);
        //  Overlay Text
        XftDrawString8(xftDraw, &xftFGColor, font, 50, 50, (XftChar8 *) text, strlen(text));

        XColor xForeColor;
        xForeColor.red = 0xafff;
        xForeColor.green = 0xafff;
        xForeColor.blue = 0xffff;
        if(XAllocColor(display,colormap,&xForeColor))
            XSetForeground(display,gc,xForeColor.pixel);
        XftColorFree(display, visual, colormap, &xftFGColor);
        XFreeColors(display, colormap, &(xForeColor.pixel), 1, 0);
    }

    XftDrawDestroy(xftDraw);
    XShmPutImage(display, window, gc, xImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, 400, 400, false);
    XSync(display, false);
    getchar();

}
```

I tried out other drivers too, with the radeon drivers i see a X error that shared pixmaps are not supported while i don't see any such error for the modesetting driver.
Has this something to do with the shared pixmaps, if yes how should i make it work with the modesetting driver.
I have been stuck on this for a while now, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/Xext/mit-shm.html

Comment: I tried running XShmqueryversion with modesetting driver , it returned value of pixmap as True, so it means shared pixmaps should be supported. I don't know what else could be causing this issue